# Can I exclude subtags when searching for a tag?

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-4, tagging, keywords

I have a question about Adobe Lightroom 4:

Say I have a keyword "parent" and a nested keyword (subtag) "child" under that keyword. Some photos are tagged with "parent", other are (only) tagged with "child".

Is it now possible to view all photos tagged "parent", but **not** see the "child" photos at the same time? Either using the keyword list or text filter, I always get to see the "child" photos also...

I know I can exclude certain keywords when searching (ie. "parent !child"), but in my case I'm having about 20 child tags, so it's not very practical to write all 20 keywords as exclusions.

Comment: In what software?

Comment: That goes exactly against why keyword hierarchies are for. It sounds like yours is wrong. I use *Family* as the parent for individuals in my family and I guess you could put *Parent* and *Child* both under that.

Comment: @mattdm: sorry, that was a stupid omission. I'm talking about Lightroom 4.

Comment: @Itai: why does that go against what hierarchies are for? I'm pretty sure all photo management programs I've used before (IDImager, Live Photo Gallery, Picasa, MediaPro, etc) don't do it that way, were they wrong? And when listing files in a folder, you don't normally get to see all files from subfolders either? Can you explain why I am doing it wrong?

Comment: Me too I have used 6 or so DAM software and those which support hierarchical keywords all assume that matching a keyword implicitly match all parent keywords. Think of each level as a refinement. If you organize your keywords with that in mind, you should not have to do searches like what you are asking.

Comment: Except some new DAM products. For example, our Daminion allows you to Show files with 'a parent tag' without sub-tags.

Comment: Thanks, Murat. I wanted to mention Daminion also,but couldn't remember the name :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, it seems the only way to do this, is using the Filter Bar. In the Keyword column, there is a little box to the right for the view settings, and here I can choose between Hierarchical and Flat. When it is on Flat, then only photos with the selected keyword are shown.